# How do i use OR statement in regex

Tags: python, regex

I have two links where i need the partNumber,the problem i am facing is in onecase it is at the end of the link and in another case it is after the query partNumber=

https://www.opsm.com.au/ProductDisplay?urlRequestType=Base&catalogId=12601&categoryId=3074457345616695670&seoNameToken=air-optix-colors-2pk&langId=-1&manufacturer=AIR+OPTIX&facetTokenValue=facet-lifecycle%3DMONTHLY&partNumber=ac-airoptix-colors-2&storeId=10151

https://www.opsm.com.au/womens-sunglasses/ov5514su-kasdan/827934482050

```
.*(?<=partNumber=)([\w-]+)

Output : ac-airoptix-colors-2
```

this is the regex i have tried but this one is working for first link. how do i put a OR condition that take the last number present in the second link

Comment: You could either capture the digits for partNumber, or capture the last number in another group `.*\bpartNumber=([\w-]+)|^.*\b(\d+)$` See https://regex101.com/r/l4bkw6/1 Do you also want to capture in `10151` in  `storeId=10151` ?

Comment: This regex pattern ensures flexibility in extracting part numbers by considering two scenarios: first, it identifies part numbers following partNumber= in the URL query string using positive lookbehind (?<=partNumber=), then it captures part numbers at the end of the URL with ([\w-]+)$. This approach accommodates variations in URL structures, providing robust extraction capabilities.

Comment: @sai i tried below regex it does't work for second link  (?<=partNumber=)([\w-]+)$

Comment: (?<=[/|partNumber=])([\w-]+)$ this one seems to work fine but getting the storeid instead of the partNUmber

Comment: If you want both and the id at the end is always present: `(?:.*?\bpartNumber=([\w-]+))?.*\b(\d+)$` https://regex101.com/r/hzAmD9/1

Comment: (?<=partNumber=)([\w-]+)|(\d+)$ 

This part captures the part number following "partNumber=" in the URL.  |: This is the OR operator, (\d+)$: This part captures the last sequence of digits in the URL. This modified pattern will capture either the part number or the last sequence of digits in the URL.

Comment: Try this regex https://regex101.com/r/UqqFGZ/1

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?<=partNumber=)[\w-]+|(?<=/)\d+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cjf9bR/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=partNumber=)[\w-]+` - one or more word or hyphen chars after `partNumber=` string
- `|` - or
- `(?<=/)\d+$` - one or more digits after `/` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

`Or` in regex is specified using `|`.